# Separate stdout and stderr for `docker run`?

Tags: pipe, docker, stdout, stderr

Can I get separate stdout and stderr pipes for `docker run`?

Example:

```
$ docker run --rm -it alpine sh -c 'echo this is stdout; echo this is stderr >&2' \
  2> stderr.txt
this is stdout
this is stderr
$ cat stderr.txt
```

What I would expect:

```
$ sh -c 'echo this is stdout; echo this is stderr >&2' 2> stderr.txt
this is stdout
$ cat stderr.txt
this is stderr
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem for you is the '-t' option. After removing it, stderr should work as expected:

```bsh
$ docker run -i --rm alpine sh -c 'echo this is stdout; echo this is stderr >&2' 2>stderr
this is stdout
$ cat stderr
this is stderr
```

When you use '-t' (or --tty) option, stdout and stderr are joined together. This isn't explicitly documented in docker because "This is the normal behavior of a tty." [Source: [moby issue 25542, comment 238647584 by bamarni](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25542#issuecomment-238622014) ]